# Smallest known asteroid with moon

Tags: asteroid, moons

The asteroid [Didymos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65803_Didymos) is only 780m in "diameter" with a moon, [Dimorphos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimorphos) only 170m across. Is Didymos the smallest object known to have a natural satellite? Also, [contact binaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_binary_(small_Solar_System_body)) where the asteroid and moon touch each-other should be excluded as the moon is not in a free orbit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may not be complete or up to date, but sorting the [List of minor planets with moons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor-planet_moon#List_of_minor_planets_with_moons) for smallest primary shows 2015 TD144 as having a 0.1 km diameter primary and 0.1 km diameter secondary. That Wikipedia article links to [Asteroids with Satellites by Wm. Robert Johnston
last updated 7 November 2021](http://www.johnstonsarchive.net/astro/asteroidmoons.html) which lists [2015 TD144](http://www.johnstonsarchive.net/astro/astmoons/am2015td144.html) having an effective diameter of 0.09 km and secondary unknown.

The source for that data is W19e: Warner, B. D., and R. D. Stephens, 2019, Near-Earth asteroid lightcurve analysis at the Center for Solar System Studies, [Minor Planet Bulletin, 46(4)](http://www.minorplanet.info/MPB/issues/MPB_46-4.pdf):423-438 which says at the top of page 435:

> **As of 2019 July, the binary with the smallest primary is 2015 TD144** (D = 0.09 km; Radar Team, 2015).